# blend with morphing

Tags: adobe-illustrator, blending

I am trying to blend between two lines within adobe illustrator in order to achieve the top blend as it appears on the enclosed image.

The bottom blend is what i am achieving but i want it to have the Morphing form of the top example, which is a stock image.

Can anyone help?

[image: blend example]

Comment: Hi Simon Jolly, welcome to GD.SE, what program are you working on? You should add the program tag at the question.

Comment: Thanks, I am working in Adobe Illustrator, have updated the question and tag now

Comment: Make sure you're working in RGB color space. It looks like you might need to play around with your stroke thickness as well.

Comment: Don't forget to mark an answer as accepted if it solves your problem, check https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3102/which-answer-do-i-accept-if-multiple-are-correct-and-work-for-me or https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers to know more

Answer (score 1):

I am not convinced that such a design is as a result of some kind of "morphing" that's any different from a regular step blend.

Recreating the exact same shape however is going to be difficult without knowing where all the anchors in the original are placed, but just as an example here is at least the beginnings of a similar shape:

[image]

You could spend hours trying to recreate something which might actually be the result of a happy accident. Rather than just copy it, why not try to create your own happy accident?  One way to do so is to use the Curvature Tool to edit the blend lines after you have made the step blend. I have found that adding extra anchors helps with creases, folds and overlaps to give that "fuller" look you are after.

Comment: Thanks Billy yes it does seem quite impossible to get the same shape, it is a client's request and i rather hoped using the same top and bottom lines would result in the same form. Not that simple sadly haha

Answer (score 0):

There are two elements that you can tweak to improve your blending: Line stroke and steps.

Increasing the line thickness will make the space between the lines smaller with the same amount of elements. The space between the lines will be more apparent.

If you increase the blending steps the lines will be closer to each other (there will be more lines) and you'll get a slightly different result, more subtle.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I understand the line thickness and blending steps options. I am trying to achieve the actual shape of the top example, which has a fuller shape to it. Cannot get the two exact same 2 lines to blend to form that exact shape.

Comment: I won't teach you how to copy a commercial design 1:1; just buy the shutterstock image if you really want the exact same shape. As Billy states on their answer, blend results depend on the position of the anchor points.

Comment: Thanks Luciano. The intention is too use the shape in different contextual designs. Doesn't have to be exact it is just the fullness i am trying to achieve however the original which is bought, is not editable as a blend.